# Filter Data When Click the Tab

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two inputs (Title and Status) and a submit button. When I click the submit button, I add input values to a table. However, the table has 3 buttons; All, Active and Completed. What I am trying to do is when I click the Active or Completed button, this button should be active and filter the data based on its "Status" value from the list. (All button should be selected by default and show all data regardless of their status)

For example, in the image below, if I click the Completed tab, this tab should be active and show me only Cook.

[image]

This was a DOM challenge I tried to solve several days ago but still cannot figure it out. I am not allowed to change anything in HTML. Only vanilla JavaScript.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"
    ></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/h8k-components@latest/dist/h8k-components.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/h8k-design@latest/dist/index.css"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <h8k-navbar header="Notes"></h8k-navbar>
      <div class="layout-column align-items-center justify-content-start">
        <section
          class="layout-row align-items-center justify-content-center mt-30"
        >
          <input
            data-testid="input-note-name"
            type="text"
            class="large mx-8"
            placeholder="Note Title"
          />
          <input
            data-testid="input-note-status"
            type="text"
            class="large mx-8"
            placeholder="Note Status"
          />
          <button class="" data-testid="submit-button">Add Note</button>
        </section>
        <div class="mt-50">
          <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="allButton">
              All
            </li>
            <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="activeButton">
              Active
            </li>
            <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="completedButton">
              Completed
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card w-40 pt-30 pb-8">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-testid="noteList"></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.tabs {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs .tab-item {
  min-width: 88px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  color: var(--heading-color);
}

.tabs .tab-item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs .tab-item:active {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

.tabs .tab-item:active::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

table tbody tr td {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 21px;
  padding: 1.6rem;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const nameInput = document.querySelector('[data-testid="input-note-name"]');
const statusInput = document.querySelector('[data-testid="input-note-status"]');
const submitButton = document.querySelector('[data-testid="submit-button"]');
const allButton = document.querySelector('[data-testid="allButton"]');
const activeButton = document.querySelector('[data-testid="activeButton"]');
const completedButton = document.querySelector(
  '[data-testid="completedButton"]'
);
const noteList = document.querySelector('[data-testid="noteList"]');
const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Hey');
  const titleNode = document.createTextNode(nameInput.value);
  const statusNode = document.createTextNode(statusInput.value);
  const trEl = document.createElement('tr');
  const tdEl = document.createElement('td');
  const tdEl2 = document.createElement('td');

  trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
  tdEl.appendChild(titleNode);
  trEl.appendChild(tdEl2);
  tdEl2.appendChild(statusNode);
  noteList.appendChild(trEl);
});
```

Comment: One way is to modify the css of the rows you want hidden and set them to `display: none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used some global variables and constants to track which `type` is selected currently.

```
let typeSelected = "all";
const allNotes = [];
```

You need to add `addEventListener` on all 3 buttons i.e `all, active, completed` so that when clicked, we can change the type.

I've added only one function `showDataInDOM()` for all functionality.

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector('[data-testid="input-note-name"]');
const statusInput = document.querySelector('[data-testid="input-note-status"]');
const submitButton = document.querySelector('[data-testid="submit-button"]');
const allButton = document.querySelector('[data-testid="allButton"]');
const activeButton = document.querySelector('[data-testid="activeButton"]');
const completedButton = document.querySelector(
  '[data-testid="completedButton"]'
);
const noteList = document.querySelector('[data-testid="noteList"]');
const tabs = document.querySelector(".tabs");

// APP STATE
const buttons = [allButton, activeButton, completedButton];
let typeSelected = "all";
const allNotes = [];

function showDataInDOM() {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let filteredNotes = [];
  if (typeSelected !== "all")
    filteredNotes = allNotes.filter((note) => note.status === typeSelected);
  else filteredNotes = allNotes;

  filteredNotes.forEach(({
    title,
    status
  }) => {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    const td2 = document.createElement("td");

    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
    td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(status));
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    fragment.appendChild(tr);
  });
  noteList.innerHTML = "";
  noteList.appendChild(fragment);
}

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const title = nameInput.value;
  const status = statusInput.value.toLowerCase();

  allNotes.push({
    title,
    status
  });
  showDataInDOM();
});

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const type = e.target.dataset.testid;
    if (type === "allButton") {
      typeSelected = "all";
      showDataInDOM();
    } else if (type === "activeButton") {
      typeSelected = "active";
      showDataInDOM();
    } else if (type === "completedButton") {
      typeSelected = "completed";
      showDataInDOM();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs .tab-item {
  min-width: 88px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  color: var(--heading-color);
}

.tabs .tab-item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs .tab-item:active {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

.tabs .tab-item:active::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

table tbody tr td {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 21px;
  padding: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <h8k-navbar header="Notes"></h8k-navbar>
  <div class="layout-column align-items-center justify-content-start">
    <section class="layout-row align-items-center justify-content-center mt-30">
      <input data-testid="input-note-name" type="text" class="large mx-8" placeholder="Note Title" />
      <input data-testid="input-note-status" type="text" class="large mx-8" placeholder="Note Status" />
      <button class="" data-testid="submit-button">Add Note</button>
    </section>
    <div class="mt-50">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="allButton">
          All
        </li>
        <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="activeButton">
          Active
        </li>
        <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="completedButton">
          Completed
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card w-40 pt-30 pb-8">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-testid="noteList"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work? I mean Active and Completed tabs do not show anything.

Comment: add `a active` and `b completed`, `c completed`

Comment: `all` will show all without filter else show category wise

Comment: Sorry, uppercase-lowercase issue.

Comment: Added `const status = statusInput.value.toLowerCase()` for case sensitive for status only

Comment: `createDocumentFragmet` is for performance reasons or?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are *not* trying to create as many code lines as possible and you do *not* want to fill the global space with as many variables as possible then maybe the following will also work for you:

```js
const tb=document.querySelector("[data-testid=noteList]");

document.querySelector("button").onclick=ev=>    // add an entry
 tb.innerHTML+="<tr><td>"
  +[...ev.target.parentNode.children]
    .filter(e=>e.tagName==="INPUT")
    .map(e=>e.value)
    .join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>";
    
document.querySelector("ul.tabs").onclick=ev=>{  // filter buttons
 if (ev.target.tagName==="LI"){
  let sel=ev.target.textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
  [...tb.children].forEach(tr=>tr.style.display=
    sel=="all" || sel===tr.children[1].textContent.trim().toLowerCase()
    ? "" : "none"  )
}}
```

```css
.tabs {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs .tab-item {
  min-width: 88px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  color: var(--heading-color);
}

.tabs .tab-item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs .tab-item:active {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

.tabs .tab-item:active::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

table tbody tr td {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 2px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <h8k-navbar header="Notes"></h8k-navbar>
  <div class="layout-column align-items-center justify-content-start">
    <section class="layout-row align-items-center justify-content-center mt-30">
      <input data-testid="input-note-name" type="text" class="large mx-8" placeholder="Note Title" />
      <input data-testid="input-note-status" type="text" class="large mx-8" placeholder="Note Status" />
      <button class="" data-testid="submit-button">Add Note</button>
    </section>
    <div class="mt-50">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="allButton">
          All
        </li>
        <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="activeButton">
          Active
        </li>
        <li class="tab-item slude-up-fade-in" data-testid="completedButton">
          Completed
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card w-40 pt-30 pb-8">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-testid="noteList"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also took the liberty of removing some random white-space around the `<td>` elements (`padding: 1.6rem`) as I would rather see *content* than white space.

Comment: It looks a little bit complicated but thank you.